# Kiosk Computer GPO

Tags: active-directory, windows-vista, group-policy

We have several kiosk PCs that are used in common areas. I have GPOs in place to lock these machines down (one GPO has all the Computer settings and another has all the User settings). These GPOs are applied to an OU that contains the User Accounts and Computer Accounts for the Kiosks. Block Inheritance is set on the OU and there are no GPOs in Active Directory that are set to Enforce. Users are only able to use the kiosks via a touch screen monitor. The way I want it set up is for the kiosks to go to a screensaver after 60 seconds and not turn the monitor off. I have set the screensaver settings (path to the scr, disabled password protect screensaver, and enabled screen saver timeout to 60 seconds).

After 60 seconds, the screensaver turns on and everything works as expected. However, after some time (maybe 30 minutes), the monitor shuts off. If I tap the screen, I see the kiosk screen. I have gone into the Power Management settings on the GPO and disabled the Turn Off Display setting. I have also created a registry setting in the GPO to change the CurrentPowerPolicy value to both 3 and 4 (either doesn't fix the issue). These kiosks are laptops running Windows Vista. I've ran the Resultant Set of Policy on them and it looks like all the settings are there. Is there something that I'm missing? Does anyone have an idea as to what else I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With touchscreen LCDs I've noticed they tend to have built-in power-saving options.  The display itself has a timer that counts how long it's been since someone touched the screen, and then goes into standby mode to protect itself.

On the displays, check the menu options accessible through the buttons on the front, and see if you can disable the built-in power-saving options.

GPOs can affect what Windows will do with the power options, but it can't tell the hardware what to.  The display itself has it's own agenda, and you need to beat it into submission.